# Disable Youtube Related Video rel=0

Tags: javascript, php

hello i want ask how make related video 0 for code im use this

```
if (ytMatch && ytMatch[1].length === 11) {
  var youtubeId = ytMatch[1];
  $video = $('<iframe>')
    .attr('frameborder', 0)
    .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId)
    .attr('width', '100%').attr('height', '360');
```

Where i should add rel=0. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd add it to the `src` url.

```
.attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId + '?rel=0')
```